# I want 2 items side by side and the same size (reCaptcha)

Tags: html, css

Can someone please help me place these side by side and both 50% of the screen? Im not sure if this is possible whilst using the reCaptcha iFrame

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="sitekey" style="transform:scale(0.5);-webkit-transform:scale(0.5);transform-origin:0 0;-webkit-transform-origin:0 0;">     </div>
<input type="submit"  class="btn-block" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" style="float:right">
```

Comment: please post what you have already tried, and the result

Answer (score 1):

Change your style tag to this `style="float: left; width: 50%;"` on each item

```html
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="sitekey" style="float: left; width: 50%;">  123 </div>
<input type="submit"  class="btn-block" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" style="float: left; width: 50%;>
```